# color of the <li> change in on mouse over and click event using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change the color of the li as red on mouse over. And keep the same color in click event also. I have the following list,

```
<html>
  <body>
     <ul>
        <li>list1</li>
        <li>list2
            <ul>
               <li>sublist1</li>
               <li>sublist2</li>
               <li>sublist3</li>
               <li>sublist4</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>list3</li>
         <li>list4</li>
     </ul>
  </body>
</html>




list1
list2
  sublist1
  sublist2
  sublist3
  sublist4
list3
list4
```

If i click the list1, it color should be change into red, at the same time if i mouse over the other list it will be displayed as red. Its default color is black.

Comment: What have you tried? Take a look at the `click()` method of jquery http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I want to highlight the active menu in click and on mouse over.

Answer (score 5):

```
// CSS: Create the highlight accessible with two classnames.

.highlight, .highlight_stay{
    color:red;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
     $('li').hover(function(){
          $(this).addClass('highlight');
      }, function(){
          $(this).removeClass('highlight');
      });

      $('li').click(function(){
           $(this).addClass('highlight_stay');
      });
});
```

To remove the click color when a different `li` is clicked change the last function to this:

```
$('li').click(function(){
     $(li).removeClass('highlight_stay');
     $(this).addClass('highlight_stay');
});
```

Comment: At first time, i click list1. It change into red color. If i click list2 at 2nd time, the list1 will change its original color and list2 will be in red color. like wise it want to work. At the same time on mouse over also want to activate the list as red color.

Comment: @ijarlax I am not sure what you are saying. Do you want to remove the red from the clicked one when you click a different one?

Answer (score 3):

Use css for that:

```
li:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

*And this is not recommended:*

```
li:focus {
    color: red;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Mouse hover - css

```
li:hover {
color: red;
}
```

if you want it to be green only wen you click - css

```
li:active {
    color: green;
}
```

if you want it to change color and remain in that color - JQuery

```
$("li").click(function (){
    $(this).css("color","green")
});
```

however you might condider reading up on `$("blah").addClass()` as it will help DOM load faster. Using css `$(this).css("color","green")` "directly" on JQuery can slow things down as project gets bigger

Comment: Just a tip that `:active` will not work well on `<li>` elements as it's meant more for links and input fields. The JavaScript approach is preferred.