# Change color <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: Example question]

I'm building a survey and what I'm trying to do now is that when someone clicks an answer (for example: 8) in my list, the background of that answer changes color. This has to work for each seperate answer (there are 60 questions).

The list html/css code:

```
<div class="answers">
    <ul>
        <li class="liFirst">1</li>
        <li class="liMiddle">2</li>
        <li class="liMiddle">3</li>
        <li class="liMiddle">4</li>
        <li class="liMiddle">5</li>
        <li class="liMiddle">6</li>
        <li class="liMiddle">7</li>
        <li class="liMiddle">8</li>
        <li class="liMiddle">9</li>
        <li class="liLast">10</li>
    </ul>
</div>

.answers {
  float: right;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  background: #DFE5E3;
}

.answers ul {
  display: inline-block;

}

.answers li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 auto; 
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I've already researched it a bit but can't seem to find a solution that works. I suppose I have to do this in JS/jQuery?

Tried this solution: [link!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854368/color-of-the-li-change-in-on-mouse-over-and-click-event-using-jquery) but didn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the following:

**JQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.answers ul li', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.answers li.selected {
    background: yellow;
}
```

You probably want to remove the selected background effect one other `<li>`s once you click on one.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9zaqn/)**

Answer (score 3):

add an active class

```
.active{
    background:#000;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

and in jquery toggle class

```
$('ul li').on('click',function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

if he wants to choose only one answer

```
$('ul li').on('click',function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: This does not ensure that the user can only choose one answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay strictly CSS based, this checkbox hack may be your best bet... http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Which can also be implemented with radio buttons to ensure only one answer can be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery**

```
$( "ul" ).on( "click", "li", function() {
    $("li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

**CSS**

```
.selected { background-color:lime;}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p2JL5/2/)**